# What does it mean when you declare a constant constructor with {super.key}?

Tags: flutter, dart, constructor

I have the following bare bones code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

//write the main method
void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

//write the MyApp class that extends the StatelessWidget class
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  //write the const ctor
  const MyApp({super.key});
  //write the build method
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'hello',
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('hello'),
          ),
          body: const Center(
            child: Text('hello'),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Note the constant constructor,

```
const MyApp({super.key});
```

I thought the curly cues {} were used for optional named parameters.

I see no name here.

What's going on?  What does it mean to pass in {super.key} into a constant constructor?

Comment: `key` is a named parameter, but it is declared on the super class (`StatelessWidget`). This is a shorthand notation for initializing super class members, which was introduced in the latest version of Dart (2.17.0) - You can read more here: https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-2-17-b216bfc80c5d#cd5e

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Dart 2.17 added a new *Super initializers*. See the image below for more information.

> In fact, when we applied the new feature to the Flutter framework, we saw a total reduction of nearly two thousand lines of code!

[image]

Reference:  https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-2-17-b216bfc80c5d

Answer (score 1):

What you probably know is this version:

```
const MyApp({this.key});
```

Which normally means you scoll up a bit and see a line like

```
final Key key;
```

This is called [initializing formal parameters](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#initializing-formal-parameters).
Now, in this specific case with the `Key`, your own widget having that key doesn't do much, you have to make sure the `Widget` super class that is somewhere in your inheritance tree knows about it, so Flutter can use it for it's logic.

So what you did in the past is this:

```
const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
```

That means you get an optional `Key` named key and then you pass it directly to the super class.

Since Dart 2.17 this has been shortened. Like the syntax for filling in your own fields, that says `this.key` as constructor parameter means this parameter goes directly into the given field, `super.key` now means that parameter goes directly into the super class constructor. So for the same code above, we end up with the code you are looking at:

```
const MyApp({super.key});
```

To quote the Dart guide on it:

> To avoid having to manually pass each parameter into the super invocation of a constructor, you can use super-initializer parameters to forward parameters to the specified or default superclass constructor.

It's in the [tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#using-constructors), but you have to scroll a little, it doesn't have it's own anchor I could link to.